# 2 delphi questions, copying code and randomizing

Tags: delphi

I'm making my first program in delphi and it's a space invaders rip off. So I have 2 questions:

First off, how would I copy code to every single object? This is what I have now:

```
    procedure TForm2.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
//Label2.Caption := IntToStr(Form2.ClientWidth);
//Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Shape2.Left + Shape2.Width);
  if smer = 1  then begin
  Shape2.Left:=Shape2.left+56;
  Shape3.Left:=Shape3.left+56;
  Shape4.Left:=Shape4.left+56;
  Shape5.Left:=Shape5.left+56;
  Shape6.Left:=Shape6.left+56;
    if Shape6.Left+Shape6.Width>Form2.ClientWidth then begin
    Shape2.Top:=Shape2.Top+56;
    Shape3.Top:=Shape3.Top+56;
    Shape4.Top:=Shape4.Top+56;
    Shape5.Top:=Shape5.Top+56;
    Shape6.Top:=Shape6.Top+56;
    smer:=0;
    end;
  end;
  if smer = 0  then begin
  Shape2.Left:=Shape2.left-56;
  Shape3.Left:=Shape3.left-56;
  Shape4.Left:=Shape4.left-56;
  Shape5.Left:=Shape5.left-56;
  Shape6.Left:=Shape6.left-56;
  if Shape2.Left<=0 then begin
    Shape2.Top:=Shape2.Top+56;
    Shape3.Top:=Shape3.Top+56;
    Shape4.Top:=Shape4.Top+56;
    Shape5.Top:=Shape5.Top+56;
    Shape6.Top:=Shape6.Top+56;
    smer:=1;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if MetakP.Visible=true then begin
    MetakP.Top:=MetakP.Top-11;
 end;
 if MetakN.Visible=true then begin
    MetakN.Top:=MetakN.Top+11;
 end;
 if MetakN.Top>Form2.Height then MetakN.Visible:=false;
 if MetakP.Top<=0 then begin
    MetakP.Left:=Image1.Left+16;
    MetakP.Top:=Image1.Top;
    MetakP.visible:=false;
    Let:=0;
 end;
 if (MetakN.left>=Image1.Left) or (MetakN.Left+MetakN.Width >= Image1.left) then begin    // da li je metak desno od kocke
    if MetakN.left<=Image1.Left+Image1.Width then begin // da li je metak levo od kocke
      If MetakN.Top<=Image1.Top+Image1.Height then begin  // da li je metak ispod kocke
        if MetakN.Top>=Image1.Top-Image1.Height then begin
          if MetakN.Visible=true then begin
            Image1.Visible:=false;//
            MetakN.Left:=Image1.Left+16;
            MetakN.Top:=Image1.Top;
            MetakN.visible:=false;
            Let:=0;
            gub:=gub+1;
            //Image1.Enabled:=false;
            end;
          end;
        end;
    end;
 end;
 if (MetakP.left>=Shape2.Left) or (MetakP.Left+MetakP.Width >= Shape2.left) then begin    // da li je metak desno od kocke
    if MetakP.left<=Shape2.Left+Shape2.Width then begin // da li je metak levo od kocke
      If MetakP.Top<=Shape2.Top+Shape2.Height then begin  // da li je metak ispod kocke
        if MetakP.Top>=Shape2.Top-Shape2.Height then begin
          if Shape2.Visible=true then begin
            Shape2.Visible:=false;//
            MetakP.Left:=Image1.Left+16;
            MetakP.Top:=Image1.Top;
            MetakP.visible:=false;
            Let:=0;
            pob:=pob+1;
            //Shape2.Enabled:=false;
            end;
          end;
        end;
    end;
 end;
end;
```

This is continued for all shapes. It's basically a hitbox check. Now, that's a lot of code, is there a way I could make it work for all the shapes separately?

Second off, how would I fire off a bullet out of a random shape? I have:

```
    procedure TForm2.Timer4Timer(Sender: TObject);
var r:integer;
var rr:string;
begin
  MetakN.Visible:=true;
  if Shape2.Visible=false then MetakN.Visible:=false;
  r:=2+random(5);
  rr:=IntToStr(r);
  MetakN.Top:=  Shape2.top+Shape2.Height;
  MetakN.Left:= Shape2.Left+Shape2.Width div 2;
end;
```

The r was supposed to be used as "Shape[r].top" and so on, but it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to make an Array of TShape or use TList<TShape> depending on your Delphi version...

Comment: The simple answer is that you don't implement it this way. Don't use a distinct shape control for each sprite. You really need to throw this all away and start again.

Comment: Another remark, it seems you are making a game. Using the VCL components for this goal is going to be slow and cumbersome. Using sprites is to correct way. Check out more appropriate tools like [DelphiX](http://www.micrel.cz/Dx/) or others...

Comment: Also, this is not one question but, rather, at least two.  The format here is one question, one answer.  I would suggest you [edit] your question to choose one of those two questions and ask the other one separately.

Comment: This is a *Question and Answer* site. Please note that neither of those are plural. If you have two questions, create two separate posts. This site is *ask a question, get an answer*, not *post multiple questions and hope someone answers*. The [help] has more details about how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs are made up of 2 parts.

1. Code
2. [Data structures](http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/142043/The_Tomes_Of_Delphi_Algorithms_And_Data_Structures.pdf)

You are only using 1.

You need to get a data structure to hold your Aliens.
Because it's just a bunch of aliens a list will work fine.

Add a variable to your form to put your aliens in.

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.Generics.Collections;

TForm1 = class(TForm)
....
private
  Aliens: TList<TShape>;
```

You can initialize your shapes on form creation.
Something like this.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  AngryAlien: TShape;
begin
  Aliens:= TList<TShape>.Create;
  for i := 0 to 100 do begin
    AngryAlien:= TShape.Create(Form1);
    AngryAlien.Parent:= Form1;
    AngryAlien.Shape:= stCircle;
    AngryAlien.Brush.Color:= clWhite;
    AngryAlien.Width:= 30;
    AngryAlien.Height:= 30;
    AngryAlien.Visible:= false;
    Aliens.Add(AngryAlien);
  end;
end;
```

Now you have a <strike>100</strike> 101 aliens.

You can move the aliens around on a timer.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  Alien: TShape;
begin
  //Move 4 aliens.
  for i := 0 to 100 do begin
    Alien:= Aliens[i];
    Alien.Visible:= true;
    Alien.Left:= Alien.Left + Random(30) - Random(20);
    Alien.Top:= Alien.Top + Random(15) - Random(10);
  end;
end;
```

Now you just use a loop to control every alien in turn.

If you want some game sample code, here something to get you started: http://delphi.about.com/od/gameprogramming/

More specifically: http://delphi.about.com/library/code/fdac_dodge_src.zip

Of course the above code is a bad example of [copy-paste anti pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming) and I would rewrite it like so:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    shp_player: TShape;
    shp_enemy: TShape;
    btnStart: TButton;
    timercircle: TTimer;
    shparea: TShape;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Shape1: TShape;
    Lbl_player: TLabel;
    lbl_circle: TLabel;
    lbl_enemy: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure timercircleTimer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  //my own category of variables
  TLevelArray = Array [1 .. 30] of Boolean;


var
  circle: array [1 .. 30] of TShape;
  Speedx: array [1 .. 30] of Integer;
  Speedy: array [1 .. 30] of Integer;
  Level: array [1..30] of TLevelArray;
  SpeedxCalculation: Integer;
  SpeedyCalculation: Integer;
  LevelStore: Integer = 1;
  HighScore: Boolean = False;

procedure ShowCircles(Level: TLevelArray);
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  for Count:= 1 to 30 do begin
    circle[Count].Visible:= Level[Count];
  end;
end;

procedure InitLevels;
var
  i,j: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 30 do begin
    FillChar(Level[i], SizeOf(Level[i]),#0);
  end;
  for i := 1 to 30 do begin
    for j := 1 to i do begin
      Level[i][j]:= true;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure Updatecircles; //if the circle needs to be visible for that level
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  for Count:= 1 to 30 do begin
    ShowCircles(Level[LevelStore]);
  end;
end;

Procedure SpeedCalculation;
begin
  circle[LevelStore].Left:= 8; //all the circles come from the same position
  circle[LevelStore].Top:= 8;
  repeat
    Randomize; //their speeds are random for more interesting gameplay
    SpeedxCalculation:= Random(10) + 1;
    Speedx[LevelStore]:= 5 - SpeedxCalculation;
    Randomize;
    SpeedyCalculation:= Random(10) + 1;
    Speedy[LevelStore]:= 5 - SpeedyCalculation;
  until (speedy[LevelStore]) and (Speedx[LevelStore]) <> 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Count: Integer;
  i: integer;
  MyCircle: TShape;
begin
  InitLevels;
  for i := 1 to 30 do begin
    MyCircle:= TShape.Create(Self);
    MyCircle.Parent:= Self;
    MyCircle.Width:= 10;
    MyCircle.Height:= 10;
    MyCircle.Brush.Color:= clmaroon;
    MyCircle.Visible:= false;
    MyCircle[i]:= MyCircle;
  end;
  Randomize;
  shp_enemy.Left:= Random(clientwidth) - shp_enemy.width;
  shp_enemy.Top:= Random(clientheight) - shp_enemy.height;
  lbl_enemy.Left:= shp_enemy.Left;
  lbl_enemy.Top:= shp_enemy.Top - 20;
  SpeedCalculation;
  updatecircles;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TimerCircle.enabled:= True;
  btnStart.Visible:= False;
  Label2.Caption:= '0';
  Edit1.enabled:= False;
  lbl_player.Visible:= False;
  lbl_enemy.Visible:= False;
  lbl_circle.Visible:= False;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  shp_player.Left:= x - shp_player.Width - 10;
  shp_player.Top:= y - shp_player.Height - 10; //the green block follows the mouse
  lbl_player.Left:= x - lbl_player.Width - 10;
  lbl_player.Top:= y - lbl_player.Height - 30;
end;

procedure TForm1.timercircleTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  overlay: Trect;
  Count: Integer;
begin
  for Count:= 1 to LevelStore do begin
    // Moves the circles

    circle[Count].Left:= circle[Count].Left + speedx[Count];
    circle[Count].Top:= circle[Count].Top + speedy[Count];

    //bounces the circles off of the boundaries of the form

    if circle[Count].Left > clientwidth - circle[Count].width then speedx[Count]:= -speedx[Count]
    else if circle[Count].Left < 0 then speedx[Count]:= -speedx[Count];

    if circle[Count].Top > clientheight - circle[Count].Height then speedy[Count]:= -speedy[Count]
    else if circle[Count].Top < 0 then speedy[Count]:= -speedy[Count];

    //detects a collision between a circle and the players block
    if Intersectrect(overlay, circle[Count].BoundsRect, shp_player.BoundsRect) then begin
      c1.Left:= 8;
      c1.Top:= 8;
      btnstart.caption:= 'Restart';
      btnstart.Visible:= True;
      LevelStore:= 1;
      SpeedCalculation;
      UpdateCircles;
      timercircle.enabled:= false;
      if HighScore = True then //if a new high score has been achieved
      begin
        Edit1.Enabled:= True;
        HighScore:= False;
      end;
      lbl_player.Visible:= True;
      lbl_enemy.Visible:= True;
      lbl_circle.Visible:= True;
      lbl_enemy.Left:= shp_enemy.Left;
      lbl_enemy.Top:= shp_enemy.Top - 20;
    end;

    //detects a collision between the player block and target block

    if Intersectrect(overlay, shp_enemy.BoundsRect, shp_player.BoundsRect) then begin
      Label2.Caption:= inttostr(strtoint(Label2.Caption) + 1);
      if strtoint(Label2.Caption) > strtoint(Label4.Caption) then begin
        highscore:= True;
        Label4.Caption:= Label2.Caption;
      end;
      Randomize;
      repeat
        //the target block goes to a new position on the form
        shp_enemy.Left:= Random(clientwidth) + 2 * (shp_enemy.width);
        shp_enemy.Top:= Random(clientheight) - 2 * (shp_enemy.height);
      until ((shp_enemy.Left) > (Form1.Left + shp_enemy.Width)) and
        ((shp_enemy.Left) < (Form1.Left + clientwidth - 2 * (shp_enemy.Width))) and
        ((shp_enemy.Top) > (Form1.Top + shp_enemy.Height)) and
        ((shp_enemy.Top) < (Form1.Top + clientwidth - 2 * (shp_player.Width)));
      LevelStore:= LevelStore + 1;
      if LevelStore = 30 then // there are only 30 circles
      begin
        MessageDlg('Congratulations! - You have completed the game!', mtinformation, [mbOK], 0);
        timercircle.enabled:= false;
        btnstart.Visible:= True;
        LevelStore:= 1;
        SpeedCalculation;
        UpdateCircles;
      end else begin
        SpeedCalculation;
        UpdateCircles;
      end;
    end;

  end;
end;

end.//FIN - Code by Si (c)
```

That way you [don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).